# Add a column to a dataframe and fill with Nan missing values

Tags: python, pandas

Hello guys I'm quite new at python and I don't know how to solve this issue. I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([10, 20, 30]), columns=['d'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([11, 21, 31, 32]), columns=['e'])

df1 = df1.join(df2['d'])
df1 = df1.join(df3['e'])
print(df1)
```

Result that I get:

```
   a  b  c   d   e
0  1  2  3  10  11
1  4  5  6  20  21
2  7  8  9  30  31
```

Result that I would like to get

```
   a   b   c    d   e
0  1   2   3   10  11
1  4   5   6   20  21
2  7   8   9   30  31
3 Nan Nan Nan Nan  32
```

The previous example was a minimal code to reproduce my issue. The point is that I want to add a column but I cannot assume that all the columns have the same length. At the very end the resulting dataframe should have a number of rows equals to the length of the longest series and the other columns should be filled with a NaN value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `concat` as it is by default  `outer`

```py
pd.concat((df1,df2,df3),axis=1)
```

or

Try `outer` join

```py
df1 = df1.join(df2['d'], how='outer')
df1 = df1.join(df3['e'], how='outer')
print(df1)
```

```
   a    b    c     d   e
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  10.0  11
1  4.0  5.0  6.0  20.0  21
2  7.0  8.0  9.0  30.0  31
3  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  32
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add how to handle the operation of the two objects that join together in the last join.

`df1 = df1.join(df3['e'])` the default how is `left`

You can use both `right` or `outer`

[Here the code]

```
df1 = df1.join(df3['e'], how='right')
```

OR

```
df1 = df1.join(df3['e'], how='outer')
```

[Here The Result]

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

for more complete information you can read the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html